# How to get information on one line in my Expression

Tags: reporting-services

My expression shows just the Name, SSN, DOB and Phonenumber.

Here's my expression:

```
=Fields!FST_NAME.Value & vbCrLf & Fields!LAST_NAME.Value & vbCrLf & Fields!SOC_SECURITY_NUM.Value & vbCrLf & Fields!BIRTH_DT.Value & vbCrLf & Fields!ATTRIB_43.Value
```

I want it to show like this

```
Name: John Smith
```

Right Now it just shows John Smith

Comment: What are you coding in?  Is this SSRS, MS Access, MS Excel?  Also, I cannot see the difference between what you want to show, and what is being shown in your question.  Both only state "John Smith" is shown.

Comment: SSRS.. I want it to say NAME then John Smith not just John Smith

Answer (score 1):

If you write one big expression your textbox will look like this:

[image]

This is hard to work with both in terms of layout and making corrections to the formula. A good alternative is to use placeholders with labels in your textbox. So you would type in "Name: " and then right click after it and select "Create Placeholder". Set the properties like this:

[image]

And the textbox can be nice to read and work with:

[image]

You can even control the formatting of the placeholders independently which comes in handy if you need to include dates or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your fields are strings, then this works:

```
=Fields!FST_NAME.Value + " " + 
Fields!LAST_NAME.Value + " " + 
Fields!SOC_SECURITY_NUM.Value + " " + 
Fields!BIRTH_DT.Value + " " + 
Fields!ATTRIB_43.Value
```

However, if Birth_Dt, or any other field is not a valid string (DateTime datatype, for example) then you will need to use CStr(Fields!BIRTH_DT.Value) to convert it to a string so it can be correctly concatenated.

In an example I can do locally my expression is as follows:

```
=CStr(Fields!ExpMonth.Value) + " " + 
Fields!ItemName.Value + " " + 
Fields!ItemClass.Value
```

The first three rows of the result it produces look like this:

```
1       1 Year Membership       1 Year      1 1 Year Membership 1 Year  
2       1 Year Membership       1 Year      2 1 Year Membership 1 Year  
3       1 Year Membership       1 Year      3 1 Year Membership 1 Year
```

To add text to the string, you can encapsulate it in quotes in your concatenated string, like this:

```
="This is added text" + " " + 
CStr(Fields!ExpMonth.Value) + " " + 
Fields!ItemName.Value + " " + 
Fields!ItemClass.Value
```

The above results now look like this:

```
1       1 Year Membership       1 Year      This is added text 1 1 Year Membership 1 Year   
2       1 Year Membership       1 Year      This is added text 2 1 Year Membership 1 Year   
3       1 Year Membership       1 Year      This is added text 3 1 Year Membership 1 Year
```